# How stream cipher works

Tags: encryption

I am new here, and I am trying to understand encryption. I have done a lot of reading here and I can not find an explanation that could help me understand.

When we are talking about stream ciphers, from what I understood, the encryption is done bit by bit.

Does that mean that the input text (let's say "Google") is encrypted character by character(because that would be byte by byte) ? Or is it converted to binary first, then the sequence of 0 and 1 is encrypted bit bi bit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> When we are talking about stream ciphers, from what I understood, the encryption is done bit by bit.

I assume you are talking about the simple XOR-ing of plaintext with the cipherstream.

Stream ciphers are often defined (theoretically, as a formal definition) as PRG (pseudo random generator) producing bit by bit with non-guessable probability. I've seen such a definition in  multiple courses. You could (in theory) apply the XOR operation bit byt bit. As you've already find out that would not be very practical in current computer architecture.

> Or is it converted to binary first, then the sequence of 0 and 1 is encrypted bit bi bit?

Practically the cipher streams are having some internal state and produces the output as stream of bytes or a byte array. As a result the string is converted as a byte array and and XOR is applied to the whole array (byte by byte or whole chunks of bytes)